# CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync throws 0x880403E9 error

Tags: windows-runtime, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a Windows Phone 8.1(winrt flavor) application and stuck in problem about PushNotification.

```
await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

This function returns `PushNotificationChannel` and it usually works well. But in *some our devices*, this function throws `0x880403E9` error.

[MSDN says,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationchannelmanager.createpushnotificationchannelforapplicationasync.aspx)

> **0x880403E9** The notification platform is in the process of reconnecting back to the WNS cloud due to a earlier network connectivity change. Apps should retry the channel request later using an exponential back-off strategy.

I think retrying the request can never solve this problem. The function always throws the exception. During a month. We even implemented exponential retrying strategy.
The worse fact is, the *our broken devices* worked well with the function before. But once it has been broken(?) by mysterious reason, it is never fixed itself. -First time we've got this problem, we did factory-reset the device and the problem fixed. But in other devices, reset was not a solution.

Somebody says [updating lastest version might solve this problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6dbe70e1-4efd-4cfc-aa6f-6a7fe00b27ea/issue-creating-wns-push-notification-channel-on-windows-phone-81-device?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK&prof=required), but it is not. Even in Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1(8.10.14157.200), the problem still occurs.

Is there anyone know about this problem?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm currently faced with it now.

Comment: @DaveDev No, not yet. I also asked it to Microsoft. And they answered they are figuring out. No solution so far.

Comment: @DaveDev I answered it myself. Check my answer. Hope this helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft answered this question via email.
The problem happened when,

- you don't have USIM card or
- exhausted your data or
- 3G/LTE network does'nt work by some problems

Even if you are connected to network with wifi, the problem still occurs. I think Windows Phone 8.1 is always trying to process the push notification by 3G/LTE network if you turn 3G/LTE data network on.
If you can't use 3G/LTE network by given reasons, try to turn off data connection at system settings. Then push notification will be proceed via wifi network.

And they said, this is not going to be fixed even in Windows Phone 8.1 GDR2. Could be with Windows 10.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, great solution, we have been struggling with this issue for a couple of days, we turned off data for the device and it worked like a charm, but i have a request for you, if you have the chance, could you share with me the email Microsoft sent you with this answer to your question? thanks, contacto@iisi.com.mx

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and the answer above fixed it.

Just want to add that there might be a problem with roaming as well. I´m working in another country then my own and I got this problem. So if the three points above is ok, check that you are not using data roaming.